# Why does the python file descriptor 'w+' erase the contents of file when used for reading?

Tags: python, file

contents of `foo.txt`

```
Hello World!
```

Two `functions`:

```
def read1(file):
    with open(file, 'r+') as fp:
        print fp.read()

def read2(file):
    with open(file, 'w+') as fp:
        print fp.read()
```

the function `read1('foo.txt')` outputs: `Hello World!`

the function `read2('foo.txt')` outputs:

It essentially outputs nothing. But why?

Not only that, the contents of `foo.txt` has been erased as well.

I thought that `w+` means you truncate the file, meaning you write over it. But I did not even use `fp.write()`.

Comment: Truncate does not mean overwrite. It means to chop down to zero size.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, ...well, the word doesn't necessarily itself imply zero size; that's just what the `open(..., O_TRUNC)` flag does. One can truncate at a different point, but that means one is completely cutting off all content after that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Truncate the file" does not mean writing over existing contents (but leaving that content present until it's overwritten); rather, it means entirely removing everything past the point at which the file is truncated. In this case, that point is the very beginning of the file.

If you want to open the file and be able to read existing contents before performing an in-place write over any subset, `r+` is the appropriate mode.

---

Quoting a definition of "truncate" from WordNet 3.0, to "truncate" something is to cut it off, or cut it short:

> truncate
>
> 3: make shorter as if by cutting off; "truncate a word";
>            "Erosion has truncated the ridges of the mountains" [syn:
>            truncate, cut short]

Thus, the name matches well with the behavior at hand.